# How to replace a substring value and take that substring to make an API call and replace with that data from the API call in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, object

I have an object:
`

```
{
    "object": {
        "id": 1,
        "string": {
            "stringWithoutData":"there is no data here"
            "stringWithData": "this is a string with this {{data.extended.action}}",
        },
    }
}
```

`I have an API with output`

```
{
    "data": {
        "extended": {
        "action": "new sub string value "
        }
    }
}
```

`I want the first object to be:`

```
{
    "object": {
        "id": 1,
        "string": {
            "stringWithoutData":"there is no data here"
            "stringWithData": "this is a string with this new sub string value",
        },
    }
}
```

`

how do I access the "object" and check if the values which are starting with '{{' and ending with '}}' and if the value with this substring exists, I have to extract that value to make an api call and based on the response, replace with the data into the object.

I did try to parse through the object but never was able to extract it properly and check the api response object for data and replace that in place of {{data.extended.action}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to access the object value, and recursively traverse the object and replace the strings.

```js
// create a replacer function
function template(str, data) {
  // replace everything bracket
  return str.replace(/{{.*?}}/g, match => {
    // split input by "." (next object)
    const spl = match.slice(2, match.length - 2).split("."); // slice to remove "{{" and "}}"
    
    return spl.reduce((obj, cur) => obj[cur], data); // go from the beginning of the object
  });
}

// recursively go though
const replace = (input, response) => {
  for(let key in input) {
    if (typeof input[key] === "string")
      input[key] = template(input[key], response);

    if (typeof input[key] === "object") {
      replace(input[key], response); // go through nested objects
    }
  }
  return input;
}


const input = {
  "object": {
    "id": 1,
    "string": {
      "stringWithoutData": "there is no data here",
      "stringWithData": "this is a string with this {{data.extended.action}}",
    },
  }
};

const response = {
  "data": {
    "extended": {
      "action": "new sub string value "
    }
  }
};
console.log(replace(input, response));
```

Comment: thank you I will implement it and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If the object always has the place holder `{{data.extended.action}}`

Then you could simply use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method modify the string.

```
const newValue = object.string.stringWithData.replace('{{data.extended.action}}', 'my new text here')
object.string.stringWithData = newValue
```

Comment: everything is dymanic here, I dont know what object I will get or what placeholder value I will get as a substring. All I know is I will get is an object with several values whose substring has a placeholder enclosed in {{}} and I have to extract that enclosed value. Using that enclosed value i have to check other api response object and replace with the value from that API object value within my current placeholder.

Hope this clears up!

Comment: I'd suggest you look at regex to capture the dynamic string in the placeholders

Comment: Yes I did find the regex value \{{[^)]*\}} to find the substring. I am having tough time looping through each and every object value to check for that placeholder and extract that placeholder value and replacing it.


1. parsing through the object to find the regex value
2. extracting that placeholder
3. replacing that placeholder